# echo varialbe nor placeholder if variable doesn't exist

Tags: php

I tried this:

```
echo $open_hour ?? 20;
```

Result:

```
20
```

But If I try this:

```
echo "My text ".$open_hour ?? 20;
```

Resul:

```
"My text"
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of brackets will show you what the PHP compiler is seeing.

Your first example is:

```
echo ($open_hour) ?? (20);
```

Which is saying...

Print the value of `$open_hour` unless it's null/undefined, then print 20. As `$open_hour` is null/undefined, it prints 20.

Your second example is:

```
echo ("My text ".$open_hour) ?? (20);
```

or, print the value of "My text `$open_hour`", unless `$open_hour` is null/undefined, then print 20.

This isn't what you're intending; so you need to use brackets.

```
echo "My text ".($open_hour ?? 20);
```